# Is there a temporary directory or direct way to upload a file in azure storage?

Tags: python, azure, file-upload, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

so I try to make a python API so the user can upload a pdf file then the API directly sends it to Azure storage. what I found is I must have a directory i.e.

```
container_client = ContainerClient.from_connection_string(conn_str=conn_str,container_name='mycontainer')
with open('mylocalpath/myfile.pdf',"rb") as data:
 container_client.upload_blob(name='myblockblob.pdf', data=data)
```

another solution is I have to store it on VM and then replace the local path to it, but I don't want to make my VM full.

Comment: I am assuming that you're receiving the file via some frontend in your API and when you receive it, you're first saving it to a file and then uploading it. Is this correct?

Comment: You can generate a SAS token with write permission for your users so that your users could upload .pdf files directly on their side without storing on server

Comment: yes, the frontend gives the API file, but I don't want to save it permanently, just after the file received it sends to the azure storage

Comment: How's going? Has your issue got resolved?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to upload it directly from the client-side to azure storage blob instead of receiving that file to your API you can use azure `shared access signature` inside your storage account and from your API you can make a function to generate Pre-Signed URL using that `shared access signature` service and return that URL to your client it will allow the client to upload file to your blob via that URL.

To generate URL can you follow the below code:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from azure.storage.blob import generate_blob_sas, BlobSasPermissions

blobname= "<blobname>"
accountkey="<accountkey>" #get this from access key section in azure storage.
containername = "<containername>"


def getpushurl(filename):
    token = generate_blob_sas(
        account_name=blobname,
        container_name=containername,
        account_key=accountkey,
        permission=BlobSasPermissions(write=True),
        expiry=datetime.utcnow() + timedelta(seconds=100),
        blob_name=filename,
    )
    url = f"https://{blobname}.blob.core.windows.net/{containername}/{filename}?{token}"
    return url


pdfpushurl = getpushurl("demo.text")
print(pdfpushurl)
```

So after generating this URL give it to the client so client could directly send the file to the URL received with PUT request and it will get uploaded directly to azure storage.

Answer (score 0):

You can generate a [SAS token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-sas-overview?toc=/azure/storage/blobs/toc.json#sas-token) with write permission for your users so that your users could upload .pdf files directly on their side without storing them on the server. For details, pls see my previous post here.

Try the code below to generate a SAS token with container write permission:

```
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient,ContainerSasPermissions,generate_container_sas
from datetime import datetime, timedelta


storage_connection_string=''
container_name = ''

block_blob_service = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(storage_connection_string)
container_client = block_blob_service.get_container_client(container_name)


sasToken = generate_container_sas(account_name=container_client.account_name,
                        container_name=container_client.container_name,
                        account_key= container_client.credential.account_key,
                        #grant write  permission only
                        permission=ContainerSasPermissions(write=True),
                        start=datetime.utcnow() - timedelta(minutes=1),
                        #1 hour vaild time 
                        expiry=datetime.utcnow() + timedelta(hours=1)
                        )

print(sasToken)
```

After you have replied to this SAS token to your user, just see this [official guide to upload files from a HTML page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/quickstart-blobs-javascript-browser), I think it would be helpful if you are developing a web app.